# Usercontrol for fullsize image

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to make an analog of viewing images like on Facebook.When you click on the image and it opens in the popup.The main problem is that the source with a link to the picture is another usercontrol from the collection.

So, I have for this usercontrol with dimming.

```
<Grid Background="#33000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FFFFFF" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="200">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#EEEEEE">
                <Label Content="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,20">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageURI}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="#EEEEEE">
                <Button Content="OK" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Width="80" Height="25" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

And also VM

```
public class PopupVM : ViewModelBase
    {

        private bool _isOpen;

        public string ImageURI { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsOpen { get { return _isOpen; } set { _isOpen = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IsOpen"); } }

        private void ClosePopup()
        {
            IsOpen = false;
        }

        public RelayCommand CloseCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public PopupVM()
        {
            CloseCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ClosePopup());
        }
    }
```

Using a usercontrol on a page

```
<local:PopupUserControl Visibility="{Binding popupVM_Instance.IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" DataContext="{Binding popupVM_Instance}"/>
```

Model for another usercontrol with image source. Collection, which is bind to a ItemsControl

```
public class DialogMessageModel : ConversationModel
    {
        public ImageAttach Image { get; set; }
        public bool HasImage => Image != null;
        public bool HasMessage => Message != null;

        public RelayCommand OpenImageCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        private void OpenImage()
        {
            TestVM.popupVM_Instance.ImageURI = Image.ImageURI;
            TestVM.popupVM_Instance.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

VM of page have Instance of PopupVM for another controls can get acces to open it

```
 public static PopupVM popupVM_Instance { get; set; }

        public TestVM()
        {
            popupVM_Instance = new PopupVM();
        }
```

Opening doesn`t work.Its visibile from start.And dont hide if I click button.Im using MVVMLight too.

Comment: Have you considered making this a popup with a style setting template and hence bindings? Your OK button could be a togglebutton with ischecked bound to isopen. I don't follow why popupvm_instance is a static.

Comment: Viewed and even implemented. The problem is that the Popup is tied to the center of the user element. And, therefore, is not always in the center. Also, the whole point is that I would like to use this for video as well.
It is static so that a custom message element, which contains a link to an image, can easily transfer it to the popup user element and also include its display.

Comment: Also the problem of the pop-up element is that it gives access to clicking outside it. But the most important thing is that it is centered relative to the user element, and not the application window as a whole.

Comment: But if you have an implementation of what I want in the form of a pop-up window, I will gladly try it. The main thing is to: dim the program window. Clicking items outside the pop-up window could not be read. And binding to a specific image, because it has not only a link, but also a lot of likes, etc.

Comment: Sounds like a templated contentcontrol would be your best option. You can put your variable content in it - so likes or an image or whatever. Make it fill whatever container it's in with a low opacity panel and then the content inside that. Take focus when shown so the user can't tab inside the window behind it.